# How to close all sessions for a user in Symfony 2.7?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

After a user changes his password (in a recover password action), I need to invalidate all sessions connected to that user (he may be logged on multiple browsers/devices) . So, after I save the user with the new password in the database, I need to close all sessions that may be active in different browsers/devices for that user. I've tried this:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
```

Also tried:

```
$this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->setAuthenticated(false);
```

And this too:

```
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);
```

Thanks in advance!

I've added this to my User class:

```
class User implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface, \Serializable{
  // properties and other methods

  public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user){
    if ($user->getPassword() !== $this->getPassword()){
        return false;
    }
    if ($user->getEmail() !== $this->getEmail()){
        return false;
    }
    if ($user->getRoles() !== $this->getRoles()){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }


  /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
  public function serialize()
  {
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt,
    ));
  }

  /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
  public function unserialize($serialized)
  {
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt
    ) = unserialize($serialized);
  }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted as I'm not entirely sure myself - reading this as you want to invalidate all the sessions connected to a user (which can be logged in on multiple browsers/devices)

Comment: Yes, is that what I need. I will rewrite the questions so that can be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sebcar,

That is a bug in the Symfony Security itself: 
[Bug explanation to be review](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17023)
[First Bug](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/13870)

So you will have to override the Abstract Token

Answer (score 6):

You need to track every session open by that user. Since he may be logged on multiple browsers/devices, he may uses different sessions.

An easy way to do it is to save a reference of the session id together with the user id, so that you can get all the sessid of an user.

```
namespace AppBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;

class LoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin',
        );
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();

        /*
         * Save $user->getId() and $session->getId() somewhere
         * or update it if already exists.
         */
    }
}
```

then register a `security.interactive_login` event that will be fired every time a user log in. You can then register the listener with

```
<service id="app_bundle.security.login_listener" class="AppBundle\Security\LoginListener.php">
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
</service>
```

After that, when you want revoke all the sessions for a user, all you need to do is retrieve all the session ids of that user, loop and destroy them with

```
$session = new Session();
$session->setId($sessid);
$session->start();
$session->invalidate();
```

Comment: Just had a tried and got `Cannot change ID of an active session`. Eg, it seems you can't invalidate third-party sessions if you are actually logged in.

Comment: you should create a new Session object. can we see your code?

Comment: Same is between `$session = new Session();` and `$session = $request->getSession();`. You can trick it with `session_id($sessid);` though instead of using `->setId();` :)

Comment: This is a good approach but what about not storing sessions in database (security wise)  but rather in let's say Redis? Plus on redis you can set a timeout for your saved entry.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#understanding-serialize-and-how-a-user-is-saved-in-the-session) in default setup you it should already happen.

> For example, if the username on the 2 User objects doesn't match for some reason, then the user will be logged out for security reasons. (...)
>   Symfony also uses the username, salt, and password to verify that the User has not changed between requests

I don't know how your User is configured but you may need to implement [EquatableInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/EquatableInterface.html)

Comment: I've updated my code following your suggestion, but still does not work, probably I'm missing something. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good, not sure why it doesn't work. May be worth little debugging and see if `isEqualTo` returns false as expected. Maybe you can introduce some extra column `version` that would count up when password gets updated and serialise it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$session->clear();`

Check the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html)

Comment: A session "communicates" one browser with the server. In this case, the user can be logged in more than one browser/device. So I need to close all the sessions that belongs to that user. I'm sorry if I miss write the question the first time.

Comment: Well, sorry I miss understand ^^